# React navigation 5 - bottom tab active borderTopColor

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm using createBottomTabNavigator and instead of coloring the whole tab or icon when a tab is active I only want to change the borderTopColor. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Maybe you should create you own `tabBarComponent` it will allow you to manipulate your bottom bar the way you want

Comment: I was thinking that if I had access to focused it would be as easy as
```
                tabStyle: {
                    borderTopColor: focused ? "red" : "white"
                }
```
Or if I could overwrite it in each screen and there set it to red and otherwise use default white.

Comment: @fuzz Did you get any solution for your above question? I am looking for a solution to use bottom tab active indicator with react navigation v5.

Comment: @PadminiS No, I ended up using a hacky solution by including a border inside the button instead.

Comment: @fuzz Thanks for your response. Something similar I am also planning , don't think currently it's going to work without a hack. Please post an answer if you'll find some clean solution in future.